# immutable-объекты и многопоточность

Tags: java, многопоточность

Доброго дня, уважаемые гуру Java. Анализирую вопросы, которые задают на собеседованиях. Пытаюсь более детально разобраться с темой immutable-объектов. К сожалению, те ресурсы, которые предлагает «Google» дают лишь очень общую информацию в стиле "immutable-объекты, это те объекты, которые не могут быть изменены в программе. Для того, чтобы объект был immutable используйте модификатор final". Как энциклопедические знания такое конечно можно сказать, на собеседовании, но думаю, там хотят слышать понимание более глубоких принципов. Кроме того, хочу написать мини-проект для лучшего понимания.

Можете ли Вы пояснить на примерах или подсказать адекватные источники, где раскрыты рекомендации по использованию неизменяемых объектов в контексте многопоточности?

Comment: В общем-то, вся суть неизменяемых объектов действительно состоит в слове "неизменяемый". Раз он неизменяемый, то у потоков нет возможности совершить над ним какое-либо несинхронизированное действие, значит, у всех потоков всегда будет актуальное значение, для изменения значения объект нужно скопировать. Под неизменяемостью, правда, скорее имелась в виду неизменяемость самого объекта, а не поля, т.е. невозможность изменить состояние объекта.

Comment: @Etki, запилите как ответ, если не трудно.

Comment: Что касается адекватных источников: ***Java Concurrency in Practice** by Brian Goetz, Tim Peierls, Joshua Bloch, Joseph Bowbeer, David Holmes, Doug Lea* - наше все.

Comment: @Nofate, это бы хорошо с примерами race condition, а я по этой части в джаве теоретик. Я постараюсь родить что-нибудь вечером.

Answer (score 22):

Для начала, есть разница между immutable-объектом (то есть, неизменяемым), и final-ссылкой.

Ключевое слово `final` для объектных типов гарантирует неизменяемость лишь *ссылки*, но не самого *объекта*. Например, если у вас есть final-ссылка на `ArrayList<T>`, вы тем не менее можете добавлять в него новые элементы или изменять существующие.

В случае же immutable-объекта объект после окончания конструктора не изменяется *вообще*. Одного лишь модификатора `final` для этого недостаточно, необходимо, чтобы все подбъекты были тоже неизменяемыми. Вы в принципе можете держать внутри ссылку на изменяемый объект, но обращаться с ним так, чтобы он не менялся.

Использование неизменяемых объектов даёт много выгод. Например, о таком объекте намного легче судить в ситуации, когда во многих частях программы есть ссылка на него (для изменяемого объекта, любая часть программы может вызвать мутирующую функцию в практически любой момент времени и из любого потока).

Но то, что для нас важно в контексте вопроса — неизменяемые объекты не требуют синхронизации при многопоточном доступе. Вот собственно и вся рекомендация: используйте неизменяемые объекты, и вам не придётся думать о том, что нужно, а что не нужно синхронизировать. Единственная возможная проблема — если вы внутри ещё не отработавшего конструктора публикуете ссылку на объект, через которую к нему может получить доступ кто-нибудь ещё, и увидеть объект в изменяющемся состоянии! (Это бывает не так уж и редко. Например, иногда программист хочет добавить объект в конструкторе в коллекцию всех объектов данного типа.)

---

Следует различать действительно неизменяемые объекты, и объекты, имеющие лишь интерфейс «только для чтения». При чтении объект тем не менее может менять свою внутреннюю структуру (например, кэшировать самый свежий запрос данных). Такие объекты не являются в строгом смысле неизменяемыми, и не могут быть использованы из разных потоков без предосторожностей. (Поэтому, если ваш объект включает другие объекты, убедитесь, что документация гарантирует их неизменяемость!)

---

Обратите внимание, что для полей неизменяемого объекта вы практически обязаны использовать `final`! Дело в так называемой безопасной публикации. Смотрите. Инструкции в Java-программе могут быть переставлены как оптимизатором, так и процессором (у Java достаточно слабая модель памяти). Поэтому, если не предпринимать специальных действий, окончание работы конструктора и присвоение значений полям может быть переставлено (но невидимо в рамках *текущего* потока)! Использование `final` гарантирует, что такого не произойдёт.

Answer (score 17):

Immutable объект - это объект, состояние которого после создания невозможно изменить. В случае Java это значит что все поля экземпляра у класс отмечены как `final` и являются примитивами или тоже immutable типами.

Пример:

```
public class ImmutablePoint {
    private final int x;
    private final int y;
    private final String description;

    public ImmutablePoint(int x, int y, String description) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

После создания экземпляра `ImmutablePoint` его модификация невозможна.

Простейший пример **immutable** класса из JDK это `String`. Любые методы, которые вы вызовите на строке (например `description.toLowerCase()`) вернут новую строку, а не модифицируют исходную.

Пример **mutable** класс из JDK - `Date`. Например `myDate.setHours(x)` модифицирует сам экземпляр myDate!

В случае многопоточного программирования преимущества immutable классов очевидны: после создания объекты можно передавать другим потокам и они всегда будут в актуальном состоянии. Т.е. вам не надо проверять не устарело ли состояние вашего экземпляра и не модифицировал ли его другой поток пока вы с ним работаете. Например, у вас есть метод `bill(Date endDate)`, в нём вы наивно проверяете соответствие endDate каким-то предварительным условиям и начинаете с ней работать. В этот момент другой поток может изменить endDate, например установит её глубоко в прошлое. Последствия могут быть самыми удивительными.

Comment: Но если поля будут immutable типами, то ссылки в таких полях можно будет менять – изменится состояние. Значит не immutable.

Comment: Поля с модификатором final не позволяют менять ссылку.

Comment: Только в вашем определении я не указано про сложные типы **с final**, или как минимум это проблематично понять.