# Зачем нужны immutable-объекты?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Мне не очень понятно, как могут использоваться такие объекты. В качестве "констант"? Но когда нужен такой объект?

Цитата из вики тоже не даёт ясности:

> В программировании неизменяемым (англ. immutable) называется объект, состояние которого не может быть изменено после создания.

Хотелось бы увидеть пример реального применения.

**Важно - хотелось бы увидеть JS-пример.**

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [immutable-объекты и многопоточность](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/432545/immutable-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c)

Comment: @Владимир там java. Я хочу JS-пример.

Comment: Посмотрите библиотеки React и Redux. Они построены вокруг неизменяемых объектов.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Представьте что Вы делаете программу для рисования, которая имеет функционал "пошаговый возврат действий". Но для того чтобы возвратится на шаг назад Вам нужно иметь слепок программы в тот самый момент. Поэтому Вы создаете такие компоненты, которые хранят свое состояние в объектах называемые `ValueObject`. После выполнения какго-то действия нужно пройтись по всей программе и собрать эти объекты, а после сохранить в каком-то хранилище, например массиве. Но тут есть одна проблема - в `javascript` не примитивные типы передаются по ссылкам. То есть Вы нарисовали первую фигуру и сохранили информационные модели в массив. После нарисовали вторую фигуру и тем самым все информационные модели изменились. Но изменились они не только в компонентах, а ещё и в тот самом массиве, в который мы сохранили данные после рисования первой фигуры. Все, программа сломалась!

Для решения этой проблемы и придумали подход в котором объекты каждый раз создаются новые и не изменяются по ходу изменения программы.

Еще очень часто приводят в пример удобство при отладки, но на мой взгляд современные отладчики делают тоже самое, показывая изменение программы по слоям. Удобство тестирования - это да, сильный аргумент, ведь можно воссоздать любой момент и быстрее разобраться в причинах бага. Отсутствие побочных эффектов - когда функция начинает работать с неизменяемыми объектами, она перестает изменять внешний код. Отсутствие утечек, на мой взгляд возможен только тогда, когда используется функциональный подход, в котором неизменяемость является фундаментальным принципом.

Comment: Хороший пример, спасибо.

Comment: А как эти все новые копии в памяти умещаются?